# How to select from database with relations?

Tags: mysql, relation

I have database with schema on picture below and I need to select everything related to one row (one id) of [letaky]. That means the related [zamestnanci], every related [obsah] and every [knihy] in it.

This is the first time i used relations in database and i have no idea how to make such a select.

[image: http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/4548/schemai.png]

Comment: Any reason for the odd naming? No particular problem with this, it's just that it'll be easier to understand the relationships if they had meaningful names. Unless that's a different language.

Comment: Yes, that's a different language. "Zamestnanci" = Employees, "idzamestnance" = "employee_id" etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use JOIN ... ON:

```
SELECT * 
FROM zamestnanci
JOIN lekaty ON lekaty.zamestnanciid = zamestnanci.id
JOIN obsah ON obsah.idletaku = lekaty.id
JOIN knihy ON knihy.id = obsah.idknihy
WHERE letaky.id = 123
```

You may also want to consider whether you need INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN for each of these joins. The difference between these JOINs is described in many other questions on StackOverflow, for example this one:

[SQL Join Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419375/sql-join-differences)

Comment: So to clarify, adding relationships within the database does not change how you select the data with a query. Would then adding the relationship just prevent accidental deletion of connected data?