# mySQL join Feature

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am using a PHP mySQL query. Struggling with a Joins.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM electors WHERE telephone > 0")
```

Then I need it to select from a table called voting_intention with matching ID from the electors table of this query and get a column called pledge that is equal to 'C' OR 'D'.

How do we do this in 1 mySQL query.

Comment: Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: also, if homework, you should put that in the tags...

Comment: [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) ?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/419397/946170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your possible SQL statement will be,

```
SELECT voting_intention.pledge
FROM electors, voting_intention 
WHERE 
      electors.id =voting_intention.id 
  and electors.telephone > 0 
  and voting_intention.pledge in {'C','D'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT * FROM electors e
JOIN voting_intention vi ON (e.id = vi.id)
WHERE e.telephone > 0 and
vi.pledge in {'C','D'};
```