# How to use for loop scenario in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I am getting multiple values from my query.

```
select l_t_id from MLTalukDetails join MLDistrictDetails on MLTalukDetails.L_D_Id=4
```

It returns 13,14,15,16. Now I want to take each of these values at a time and get the details from those values i.e.

```
select Sc_Id from MSchoolDetails 
where 
MSchoolDetails.L_T_Id=@talukid and 
MSchoolDetails.Y_Id=@yearid
```

What can i do this scenario. How can I use the for loop syntax here?

Comment: you can use the [pl/sql](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL) for this it will provide the looping and conditioning

Comment: Why would you need a "for loop" if you could simply use a single join query? BUT given that, you might want to rather look into using a CURSOR if you MUST!!!http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: It *is* possible to use cursors, but it sounds like you're still actually looking for some sort of set operation/join.  You'd loop through the result in your app if you have one processing the rows returned.

Comment: May be you are looking for [Correlated Subqueries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inferring from your question that this is the complete solution you're actually looking for:

```
    SELECT MSchoolDetails.* 
      FROM MLTalukDetails
INNER JOIN MSchoolDetails ON MTalukDetails.l_t_id = MSchoolDetails.L_T_Id
     WHERE MLTalukDetails.L_D_ID = 4 AND MSchoolDetails.Y_Id=@yearid
```

*Normally* one has a join condition which involves both tables.

I'd suggest [reading up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419375/sql-join-differences) on the various joins.

Comment: thank you very much. my problem is, i have to display number of students in each school. input i m getting is district code so i ll get district id i.e. MLTalukDetails.L_D_ID. from ur code i can get all the schools in district. now how can i count no students in each school. relation between school and students is  sc_id. i'm newbie here so please help me out.

Comment: by below code i can get the no of students passed in district. select COUNT(Md_Id)as noofpassed from MMarksDetails
join MStudentDetails
on MMarksDetails.St_Reg=MStudentDetails.St_Reg
join MSchoolDetails
on MStudentDetails.Sc_Id=MSchoolDetails.Sc_Id
join MLTalukDetails
on MLTalukDetails.L_T_Id=MSchoolDetails.L_T_Id
join MLDistrictDetails
on
MLDistrictDetails.L_D_Id=MLTalukDetails.L_D_Id
where MLDistrictDetails.L_D_Id=4 and MMarksDetails.Y_Id=7 and MMarksDetails.Result='p';like this i need for whole district.

Comment: This is the type of structure you would use to accomplish that: `SELECT school_id, COUNT(student_id) FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY school_id`

Answer (score 0):

Use cursor if you want to use loop....Here is workaround for you which I have implemented in stored procedure....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_GetSc_Id]
@yearid INT
AS
CREATE TABLE #Sc_Id(Sc_Id varchar(20))
BEGIN       
DECLARE @talukid varchar(20)

    declare c cursor For 
    select l_t_id from MLTalukDetails join MLDistrictDetails on MLTalukDetails.L_D_Id=4

open c
    fetch next from c into @talukid
    while(@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
    BEGIN
        insert into #Sc_Id(Sc_Id) 
            select Sc_Id from MSchoolDetails where MSchoolDetails.L_T_Id=@talukid and MSchoolDetails.Y_Id=@yearid
        fetch next from c into @talukid
    END
    select * from  #Sc_Id;---Here you got your final result.
close c
deallocate c
DROP TABLE #Sc_Id
END
```

Comment: It's not an incorrect answer, per se, I just don't think it's particularly helpful to answer a basic question with an obvious [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) straight up while also introducing completely unrelated concepts (stored procedures) with no explanation whatsoever.

Comment: @mootinator : Thanks for commenting.....I think OP want to implement looping mechanism in its solution....So, I provide above workaround though there are other efficient solution.....About stored procedure, I think it's the good way to work with sql server....