# merge 2 tables based on key and get matching columns sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables that has 2 columns as described below, both these tables needs to be merged on a particular columns(col1), if it matches, I need other columns(col2,col3) from both the table..

```
table_1

col1 col2
1     A
2     B
3     C

table_2

col1 col2
1     A1
2     B1
3     C1
4     D1

Result:

COL1 COL2  COL3
1     A1    A
2     B1    B
3     C1    C
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Join Differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419375/sql-join-differences)

Comment: Could you give us some code that you have tried using to do this?

Comment: It looks like you want to "join" two tables, not "merge."  A search for SQL join information should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `join`.

```
select t1.col1, t2.col2, t1.col2 as col3
from
    table_1 t1
          inner join table_2 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1
```