# query for row data as columns in mssql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following tables

```
1. Ledger
LedgerId       LedgerName
  1            Cash acoount
  2            My Account

2. Transaction 
TransactionId      EntryDate
     1             26/5/2014

3. DebitCredit
DebitCreditId      TransactionId   LedgerId    IsDebit    Amount
      1                 1             1           0       50.00
      2                 1             2           1       50.00
```

My output should be

```
Date         Debit Ledger Name         Credit Ledger Name      Amount
26/5/2014     My Account                   Cash Account          50
```

if IsDebit is 1 the corresponding Ledger name comes to Debit Ledger Name otherwise comes to Credit Ledger Name

Please give the query for this

Help me 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything before posting the question???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using [JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419375/1048425):

```
SELECT  Date = t.EntryDate,
        DebitLedgerName = dl.LedgerName,
        CreditLedgerName = cl.LedgerName,
        d.Amount
FROM    [Transaction] AS t
        INNER JOIN DebitCredit AS d
            ON d.TransactionID = t.TransactionID
            AND d.IsDebit = 1
        INNER JOIN Ledger AS dl
            ON dl.LedgerID = d.LedgerID
        INNER JOIN DebitCredit AS c
            ON c.TransactionID = t.TransactionID
            AND c.IsDebit = 0
        INNER JOIN Ledger AS cl
            ON cl.LedgerID = c.LedgerID;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef538/5)**