# What is the difference between left outer join and join?

Tags: sql

in below query i used join (i need the get the all the Students Zypcoins)

```
select a.strAssociateId, 
a.strAssociateName, 
a.strPhoto, 
isnull(sum(iCount),0) as zypcoins
from CIOChallenge_tbl_Associates a 
join CIOChallenge_tbl_AssociatePoints ap 
on
a.strAssociateId=ap.strAssociateId
and
ap.iRewardId=1
where iRoleId=(select iRoleId from CIOChallenge_tbl_Roles where strRoleDescription like           '%student%')
group by a.strAssociateId, 
a.strAssociateName, 
a.strPhoto
```

here i used left outer join

```
select a.strAssociateId, 
a.strAssociateName, 
a.strPhoto, isnull(sum(iCount),0) as zypcoins
from CIOChallenge_tbl_Associates a 
left outer join CIOChallenge_tbl_AssociatePoints ap 
on
a.strAssociateId=ap.strAssociateId
and
ap.iRewardId=1
where iRoleId=(select iRoleId from CIOChallenge_tbl_Roles where strRoleDescription like '%student%')
group by a.strAssociateId, 
a.strAssociateName, 
a.strPhoto
```

can i know the difference between above two query also is there any other way to get the students zypcoins

Comment: You'll see the difference if not every student have points in corresponding table. Inner join will just remove this entries while outer join will fill them with NULLs.

Comment: See the [Visual Explanation of SQL JOINs](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) for a great explanation of those differences.

Comment: yeah! thanks for sharing marc :) nice blog

Comment: Just a side note: It is strange to see the sub-select result being retrieved with like but be considered to be one record only. I would have expected `iRoleId IN (select ...)`. If you know `like '%student%'`will retrieve just one record (so you use `iRoleId = (select ...`), how come you don't know the exact string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Join Differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419375/sql-join-differences)

Comment: if i don't know exact sting value instead of like %student%. directly i can give IRoleId value (i.e) IRoleId=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned about JOINS from here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp . You can also apply some examples and test them. As a general answer.

`JOIN` - get rows that are in the both tables(or subquerys) that are joined

`LEFT OUTER JOIN ( LEFT JOIN )` - get all the rows from the left table(subquery) and for the rows where there is no match in the second table(subquery) inserts null.

`RIGHT OUTER JOIN ( RIGHT JOIN )` - get all the rows from the right table(subquery) and for the rows where there is no match in first table(subquery) it inserts null.

`FULL OUTER JOIN ( FULL JOINS )` - get all data from both tables and where there is no match in first or second table it add null.

As a fact always use the condition to join a PK/FK or an intexed column, it will make your query a lot faster.