# Lookup/Link two MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, json, lookup

I'm fairly new to SQL and have been trying to figure this one out for a while.

I have tableA with Club_Name, Image_Path,... and then I have tableB with Club_Name, Article,...

I am exporting tableB to a JSON array and need to include Image_Path, how can I best do this? If I ad an Image_Path column to tableB is there a means to conditionally populate it based on Club_Name and a lookup to tableA?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Join Differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419375/sql-join-differences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `join` the 2 tables together, based on a column value that exists in both tables.. ..in your case: 'Club_Name'

```
SELECT a.Club_Name, a.Image_Path, b.Article
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b USING (Club_Name)
```

Comment: worked great thanks, saved as view and can send this to JSON instead