# How can I join 2 tables?

Tags: join

I would like to join tables .  Could you please help?

Select Number, OwnerId from DNIS.numbers

select ID,Name  from DNIS.owners

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Join Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419375/sql-join-differences)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, `SQL` servers allow you to join tables from different databases as long as the former all belong to them. Here is an example showing you how to do this (all you have to do is to explicitly write the database names associated to each table in the query):

```
SELECT N.Number, N.OwnerId, O.ID, O.Name
FROM DB1.[dbo].DNIS numbers N
JOIN DB2.[dbo].DNIS owners O ON O.ID = N.OwnerId
```

You can also use the following syntax:

```
SELECT N.Number, N.OwnerId, O.ID, O.Name
FROM DB1..DNIS numbers N
JOIN DB2..DNIS owners O ON O.ID = N.OwnerId
```

Comment: Awesome.  Than you Tommaso Belluzzo

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish that you will have to specify the table and column names in your join statement, like so:

```
SELECT db1.tablename.column, db2.tablename.column
  FROM db1.tablename INNER JOIN db2.tablename
  ON db1.tablename.id = db2.tablename.id;
```

Comment: Great.  Thank you Leo.